# Terminal requires ^C every so often after running (seemingly any) Python program?

Tags: command-line

I am working on a Python program and running it from my terminal. Everytime I run it, it returns to the `$` prompt, though about 10% of the time I have to hit ^C to get the prompt to respond to my input. I also noticed that when I go to hit up arrow to run the last command the first letter is missing.

[image]

I cannot seem to reproduce the steps exactly to create the issue, it just seems to happen at random. Any ideas on what is causing this?

**EDIT:** Also to note. I am running this installation from a VM. I am also using Alt+Tab to switch between my editor and the termial and quickly pressing up arrow+Enter to start the script running. Maybe its my timing hitting some sort of keyboard shortcut?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of switching between my Python file in a text editor and the command line so often I was occasionally hitting ^S out of habit of saving the file often, but when I was in the command line and not the text editor.

Hitting ^S on the command line reproduces the issue.